# Changing the input shape of Pre-Trained Models in KERAS (TF Backend)

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, keras, pre-trained-model

I am using transfer learning with the **pre-trained model** using KERAS with TensorFlow Backend. Now, I want to change its input shape but I am unable to do it.

Following are the current shapes:

```
model.input_shape : `(None, 16, 112, 112, 3)`

model.layers[0].get_weights(): `(3, 3, 3, 3, 64)`

Output shape of first Layer : `(None, 16, 112, 112, 64)`
```

What I am trying to do is to change the `input shape to (None, 112, 112, 112, 1)`.

I did try to change the input in json file but I got the error in it.